# Disclosure Indicator and Detail Disclosure

Tags: iphone, user-interface, uitableview

I have a table view cell, which is acting like button, performing some action without additional user interface presentation, then it will update the same cell with results of action. What type of accessory would be appropriate for such cells?

I would like to know in which cases I should use the subject types.

Answer (score 0):

If you are keeping the cell in place, without any navigation, but will update the contents of the cell I don't think you need any disclosure accessory there. The flash as the cell is selected and deselected - and of course the change in the cell's visible content - should be enough. It would be more misleading in my opinion to show a disclosure indicator, with its implications of navigation, and then to remain in place.